# std::string replace "&" with "&amp;"

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to replace all occurrences of only `&` with `&amp;` in a string.
But I have to skip it if `&` is followed by a `;`, i.e. if `&amp;` or `&engrave;` etc. is there it is not to be modified.

I have written the [following code](http://cpp.sh/6o5mq) and it seems to be working well, but I'm doing too many comparisons I think - is there a better way do it? I can use boost or c++11.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "An R&D string with one more R&amp;D here and S&D or T&engrave; Some More T&D and &amp;&engrave; and R&&D";
    std::cout<<"original string is : "<<str<<std::endl;
    int index = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        std::string::size_type n = str.find("&",index);
        if(n == std::string::npos)
            break;
        std::string sub = str.substr(n+1, 10);
        std::string::size_type m = sub.find("&");
        std::string::size_type b = sub.find(";");
        if(m != std::string::npos && m<b)
        {
            auto temp = sub.substr(0,m-1);
            sub = temp;
        }
        if(sub.find(";") == std::string::npos)
        {
            str.replace(n, 1, "&amp;");
        }
         index = n+1;
    }
    std::cout<<"changed string is : "<<str<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The given logic will apparently fail to replace the & given the following string "Dungeons & Dragons, and how about a semicolon, like this one: ;". Is this your expected result?

Comment: For boost, there's [boost::spirit::xml::encode](https://www.tena-sda.org/doc/5.2.1/boost/d3/df1/namespaceboost_1_1spirit_1_1xml.html).

Comment: You may want to use regex

Comment: How about `"Dungeons & colons ;"` - what's the expected outcome here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the expected output is `"Dungeons &amp; colons ;"` My bad in explaning the question wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this looked like  something [std::sregex_token_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) would be good at (though its not likely to be the fastest solution). So I came up with this that seems to do the job:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "An R&D string with one more R&amp;D here and S&D or T&engrave; Some More T&D and &amp;&engrave; and R&&D";

    std::cout << str << '\n';

    // match HTML style entities aka &amp;
    std::regex e(R"(&\S+;)");

    // iterate through matches (0) and non-matches (-1)
    std::sregex_token_iterator itr(str.begin(), str.end(), e, {-1, 0});
    std::sregex_token_iterator end;

    for(; itr != end; ++itr)
    {
        std::string s = *itr;

        // replace the "&" in non-matching portions of the string
        if(!std::regex_match(s, e))
            s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("&"), "&amp;");

        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. that worked :)

Answer (score 1):

The main inefficiency is here:

```
std::string sub = str.substr(n+1, 10);
```

Any time you create a while new substring, it is very inefficient. A secondary inefficiency is that you are using std::string::replace(), which must move the tail of the string.  In the general case, this leads to O(N*N) behavior.

Also your question is somewhat poorly defined.  I *think* this specification can be improved to something like:

- Replace & with &amp;
- Unless the & is followed by a sequence of letters terminated with ;

The following code is reasonably efficient:

```
std::string replace(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        if (c != '&') {
            result += c;
            continue;
        }
        bool replace = false;
        bool haveAlpha = false;
        for (int j = i + 1; true; j++) {
            if (j >= str.size()) {
                replace = true;
                break;
            }
            char c2 = str[j];
            if (isalpha(c2)) {
                haveAlpha = true;
                continue;
            } else if (c2 == ';') {
                replace = !haveAlpha;
                break;
            } else {
                replace = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (replace) {
            result.append("&amp;");
        } else {
            result += c;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "An R&D string with one more R&amp;D here and S&D or T&engrave; Some More T&D and &amp;&engrave; and R&&D";
    std::cout << "original string is : " << str << std::endl;
    std::cout << "replaced string is : " << replace(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the right thing, but of course stackoverflow wants to interpret all of those nice escapes :-)  You'll just have to run it.